# OCR - Tesseract test not parsed correctly

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, ocr, tesseract

I am currently working with tesseract. The thing is that the text is not parsed correctly.

Here is my code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include "baseapi.h"
#include  "leptonica\allheaders.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
using namespace System;
using namespace std;

void writeFile(char* filename, char* content);
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    char* output;
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *baseApi = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

    if (baseApi->Init("C:\\Users\\fss-dk\\Downloads\\tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar\\tesseract-ocr\\", "eng"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not init\n");
    }

    Pix *image = pixRead("D:\\eng.jpg");
    char *text = image->text;
    baseApi->SetImage(image);
    output = baseApi->GetUTF8Text();

    writeFile("D:\\test.txt", output);
    baseApi->Clear();
    baseApi->End();

    pixDestroy(&image);

}
void writeFile(char* filename,char* content)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open(filename);
    file << content;
    file.close();

}
```

The code works fine and writes the content to the file.

Is there anything I should think of to get this working?

I've tried with 20 different images.

Comment: it is not 100% guaranteed that the OCR will work perfectly. It is a very difficult job to do. Try to increase the resolution of the images

Comment: Is there any built in function to do that with tesseract?

Comment: @user3514987: he's telling you that you may have to increase the resolution of the *original image*, there's no function that can invent data that isn't there in first place...